# jQuery Navigation with history.PushState()

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json, include

I want to create a navigation like here: http://html5.gingerhost.com/

I'm following this tutorial: http://moz.com/blog/create-crawlable-link-friendly-ajax-websites-using-pushstate

Actually finished and seems like it is working but I have questions on how to improve it (I think that I did something wrong, not the author of the tutorial)

My folder structure:

```
localhost
  -/try
    -script.js
    -index.php
    -content.php
    -/New York
      -index.php
      -content.php
```

index.php (all are similar, just title header and article are different)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Home Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header id="header"><h2>Home</h2></header> <!-- end header -->
    <div id="content">
        <div id="loading"></div>
        <nav>
            <ul id="menu"> 
                <li><a href="/Try">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Try/Seattle">Seattle</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Try/New York">New York</a></li>
                <li><a href="/Try/London">London</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    <div id="main">
        <article>
            <div id="articletext">
                <p>This is home page</p>
            </div> 
        </article> <!-- end post 1 -->
    </div> <!-- end main -->
    </div> <!-- end content --> 
    <footer id="footer"><p>Copyright &copy; 2011</p></footer> <!-- end footer -->
</body>
</html>
```

script.js ( its from this tutorial just changed `$.getJSON("/content.php",... to $.getJSON(url+"/content.php",`

```
// THIS IS WHERE THE MAGIC HAPPENS
    $(function() {
        $('nav a').click(function(e) {
            $("#loading").show();
            href = $(this).attr("href");

            loadContent(href);

            // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
            history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
            e.preventDefault();     
        });

        // THIS EVENT MAKES SURE THAT THE BACK/FORWARD BUTTONS WORK AS WELL
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            $("#loading").show();
            console.log("pathname: "+location.pathname);
            loadContent(location.pathname);
        };
    });

    function loadContent(url){
        // USES JQUERY TO LOAD THE CONTENT
        $.getJSON(url+"/content.php", {cid: url, format: 'json'}, function(json) {
                // THIS LOOP PUTS ALL THE CONTENT INTO THE RIGHT PLACES
                $.each(json, function(key, value){
                    $(key).html(value);
                });
                $("#loading").hide();
            });

        // THESE TWO LINES JUST MAKE SURE THAT THE NAV BAR REFLECTS THE CURRENT URL
        $('li').removeClass('current');
        $('a[href="'+url+'"]').parent().addClass('current');    
    }
```

And my content.php all files are the same just other values.

```
{
"h2":"Home",
"title":"Home",
"article #articletext":"This is Home page"
}
```

1) I guess the author doesn't have `content.php` for every page. How would I put it in one? Is that possible? I even wonder if my `content.php` looks how it should. Please correct it if I am wrong.

2) I want load page content from `content.php`, sometimes content will be long, it will contain many divs so I need indentation in the text but I can not create "enters". I mean everything has to be in one line else it doesn't work. Obviously it's not clear and it's hard to edit later; How to solve this? (I sense that an answer for the 1st questions is what I am looking for :P) I tried to put `"article #articletext":"<?php include('HomeContent.php'); ?>" instead of "article #articletext":"This is Home page"` in content.php file, but it doesn't work, nothing from content.php loads.

Researched this forum and internet and still I don't have a solution, just found similar questions without answers... :<

Answer (score 1):

why not just use jquery .load, then have your content be dynamically loaded from the database? just have one content.php that is formatted however you want, take the city as a querystring parameter and pull the correct data into the formatted content.php. then you would just do

```
<ul id="menu"> 
    <li><a href="/Try">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Try/Seattle">Seattle</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Try/New York">New York</a></li>
    <li><a href="/Try/London">London</a></li>
</ul>

$('nav a').click(function(e) {
    $("#loading").show();
    href = $(this).attr("href");
    load_param = href.replace('/Try/',''); 
    $('#content_div').load('/content.php?city=' + load_param); // loads content into a div with the ID content_div

    // HISTORY.PUSHSTATE
    history.pushState('', 'New URL: '+href, href);
    e.preventDefault();     
});
```

this way you won't have to worry about parsing JSON or anything, and the formatting from the content.php will be applied once the document is done loading.

Comment: Thank you for answer i thought my question will disappear in tones other questions. As i said i would recreate navigation from tutorial, in your solution i have to add "?city=param" to link what i dont want to do, and dont quite understand how to format content.php, how to divide it, i mean how server will know which part of content.php i request, short example please :) ?

Comment: this is basic web programming knowledge, you would put the information into the database, then in your content.php load the correct content from the database based on the query string parameter.

Comment: @Chris Brickhouse hi, have you managed to solve this problem?